# The physical interpretation of Newton's constant $G$

Tags: gravity, physical-constants

It is well known that the speed of light $c$ can be interpreted as the speed limit for information propagation. Similarly, the Planck's constant $h$ is interpreted as the minimum quantum package of action/entropy. Is there a similar interpretation for the Newton's constant $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any interpretation in some sense underlines the property that you find interesting.
Maybe Schwarzschild radius or Planck's mass could be used to give a satisfactory interpretation of G. Otherwise it's just a coupling const. like the fine structure const.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any such "limit" interpretation of $G$. The universal gravitational constant $G$ is defined by the Law of universal gravity:

Magnitude of the mutual attractive force two bodies exert on each other is given by
$$
F = G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r_{12}^2},
$$
where $m_1$, $m_2$ are masses of the two bodies and $r_{12}$ is their mutual distance, and is oriented towards the other body. Gravitational constant $G$ is the constant of proportionality in the above equation. In the SI system of units, the constant $G = 6.67\times 10^{-11}$ gives force in newtons, acting on 1 kg body due to another 1 kg body at distance 1 m (this is close to the way $G$ is measured).